# the problem I encounter is that the @ cacheable sync attribute does not take effect

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, updates, spring-data-redis

I have been granted the task of refactoring the cache. The version of springboot we use is 1.5.6. I want to upgrade the spring data redis version to 1.8.22. Because there are bugs in the get method of the previous version. Now the problem I encounter is that the @ cacheable sync attribute does not take effect. But the sync attribute of version 2. X takes effect. Is this the problem of the version? How can I prevent cache penetration in this version

```
 @Cacheable(sync = true,value = "emp")
    @Override
    public User selectUser(Long id) {
        System.out.println("query 1");
        return userMapper.selectUser(id);
    }
//I use JMeter for concurrent testing
//and the sync attribute doesn't effect.
```

Comment: Help me ,please!

Comment: When you don't mention the ```key``` attribute as a parameter to Cacheable annotation, it starts using its own keys which might be different for different invocations, even if the ```id``` is same. That's why it might not work as you expected. So try to define your Cacheable annotation with another parameter ```key="#id"```.